# Why should Disable IpV6 Hadoop Installation

Tags: hadoop

I've succesfull install and running Hadoop on Ubuntu system.
I'm following tutorial on some article.

I'm confuse why every step suggest to disable ipv6 ?

Is there effect if i don't disable my ipv6 on my system ?

Anyone can answer it ?

Comment: I think there is a bug with ipv6 for hadoop. It might bring problem down the line if you dont disable ipv6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIPv6): Apache Hadoop is not currently supported on IPv6 networks. It has only been tested and developed on IPv4 stacks. Hadoop needs IPv4 to work, and only IPv4 clients can talk to the cluster.If your organisation moves to IPv6 only, you will encounter problems.

Take a look at [HADOOP-3437](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3437)  and [HADOOP-6056](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6056) to understand why it is necessary to disable IPv6 to get Hadoop working.

Comment: It is still required to disable IPv6 now a days?

Comment: Disabling it is never a requirement. Enabling or running on IPv6 are different things. Although you should know that Hadoop will run on IPv4 and will not be able to comunicate with IPv6 configured (not only enabled but that runs on IPv6) network members.