# setsockopt IPV6_TCLASS 16: Protocol not available, Cygwin64

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I'm trying to install Hadoop 1.0.3 using Cygwin64 on Win8.1. After I completed the config, started SSHD service, I run ssh cyg_server@localhost and got these:

```
cyg_server@localhost's password:
setsockopt IPV6_TCLASS 16: Protocol not available:
```

I'm complete new with Cygwin64 and Hadoop, thanks advance for any help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue -- will let you know if I solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the client side, just add

> -oAddressFamily=inet

to the parameters passed to `ssh`, or add

> AddressFamily inet

to `~/.ssh/config`, either globally or per a specific host.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my issue also! However, now I receive an error when trying to start Hadoop it is attempting to use IPV6. I'm calling "$ bin/start-all.sh" and cannot specify the addressfamily to use.

Comment: How can I add "-oAddressFamily=inet" to the parameters passed to ssh?

Comment: Where you would typically type "ssh [user@]host" add the parameters to the command line.  So: "ssh -oAddressFamily=inet [user@]host".  Regarding Hadoop still not permitting a connection, refer to <http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIPv6> and <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758641/why-should-disable-ipv6-hadoop-installation>.

Comment: Now the same problem when run "$bin/start-all.sh", so it's still not a prefect solution.

Comment: it's like this "localhost: setsockopt IPV6_TCLASS 8: Protocol not available: "

Comment: If start-all.sh is invoking ssh and you cannot add the option to its commandline invocation, then you should try the config file method. Just make sure that ssh is using the config file you think it is.

Comment: Downvoted because this is a magical incantation with no explanation of what it does or why it works.  I dislike magical incantations.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to turn off IPV6 and use IPV4.  To do this, stop your sshd service if you have it running:

```
net stop sshd
```

Then edit the file `/etc/ssh_config` by adding (or modifying) the `AddressFamily` setting:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

The default is set to `all`.  Setting the value to `inet` forces IPV4 which fixed the problem for me.  After you make the change, restart sshd and you should be good to go:

```
net start sshd
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried this and received an immediate "closed by remote host", when I tried to login via either localhost or local IP.

Comment: ok. got that resolved. I had a "." in front of the "#" I used to make a comment in sshd_config.

Answer (score 1):

I had a simmilar issue with Cygwin logging in to IPv6-enabled Servers.

Upgrading Cygwin (on client side) to the lastest version solved my problem.

I'm tired of all the "Just disable IPv6" suggestions. **We have 2014 and IPv6 is here.** We should better fix bugs and issues with this "new" protocol instead of negating ist.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when OpenSSH attempts to set the "type of service" field for an IPv6 connection on a system that defines `IPV6_TCLASS` in `<sys/socket.h>`, but where the kernel doesn't support it (a 2.4-series kernel or older versions of Cygwin).

It may reduce performance in a situation where something is performing traffic shaping/QoS, but is otherwise harmless.

Answer (score 0):

If you see such issue on WSL1/OpenSSH client and you need to use IPv6 protocol
then try to use `ssh -oIPQoS=none ...`
or add `IPQoS none` to your `~/.ssh/config` or systemwide SSH config.

As Mark mentioned here it may be due to unsuccessful attempt to set "type of service" for IPv6 connection.